# touchesMoved for Multiple UIImageViews

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, touchesmoved

I have multiple `UIImageViews` placed producing an NxN grid view on a `UIView` added programmatically, and all have their **userInteractionEnabled** property set to **YES**.

**EDITED**

I now have another issue, where if I start dragging on a UIImageView and hover on other UIImageViews only the first one is calling touchesMoved method. E.g. a sample NSLog with the [[touches anyObject] view.tag] within touchesMoved method will print:

```
Log: touchesBegan for object with tag=123
Log: touchesMoved for object with tag=123
Log: touchesMoved for object with tag=123
...
Log: touchesEnded for object with tag=123
```

Is it any way to do that? I basically want to highlight the selected cell if the user drags over the UIImageViews dynamically.

Comment: Did you also implement the `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded`, and `touchesCanceled` methods?  And if so, are they getting called in the nominal sequence (began -> (typically multiple) moved -> ended)?  You do need to implement all of these.

Comment: @bobnoble Obviously I had a mistake - i have been removing and re-adding UIImageView's as soon as the touchesBegan method was called and that was the reason. I have now edited the question, as I have a completely different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ([touch view] == img1) { 
   // move the image view
   img1.center = touchLocation;        
}
else if ([touch view] == img2) {
    // move the image view
   img2.center = touchLocation;        
}
```

Comment: My question does not involve moving of any of the UIImageView's. I only want to highlight (e.g. change backgroundColor, or Image) the appropriate cell while user keeps dragging around the view.